# multiple toml file not recognised for [file] backend

Tags: docker, traefik

I have simple toml configuration file

```
    defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
    logLevel = "DEBUG"
    debug = true
    [entryPoints]
      [entryPoints.http]
      address = ":80"

    [file]
     directory = "/etc/traefik/rules.d/"
     watch = true
```

the toml files inside rules.d/ are not recognised nor loaded, I am using latest docker build of traefik. If I use filename instead of directory, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using 1.3.8, the support of `directory` come with 1.4 (https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/1672)